# Insert into table with subtype column: Type Inheritance, Object Oriented SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

when i try to insert data into following table.

```
create table Policies of policy_t(
pid primary key,
inscar references Cars
)nested table claims store as  claims_ntable;
```

using following query,

```
insert into policies
        select policy_t ('PLC1234','12 Mar 2017','12 Mar 2018',REF(C),175000,claim_t('CLAIM1234567','12 Feb 2017','56000',REF(T)))
        from cars C,customer T
        where C.regno = 'CAB3233' and T.cid = '123ABC'
```

and i get following error

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
insert into policies
select policy_t ('PLC1234','12 Mar 2017','12 Mar    2018',REF(C),175000,claim_t('CLAIM1234567','12 Feb 2017','56000',REF(T)))
from cars C,customer T
where C.regno = 'CAB3233' and T.cid = '123ABC'
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 25
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

How to insert data into this table?

Other related Object types and tables,

Customer object type

```
create type Customer_t as object(
cid char(6),
cusname varchar(15),
birthdate date,
phone char(10),
address varchar(50)
);
```

Customers table

```
create table Customers of customer_t(
cid primary key
);
```

Claim Object type

```
create type claim_t as object(
claimno char(12),
cdate date,
amount number(8,2),
claimant ref customer_t
);
```

Claim nested table

```
create type Claim_ntab is table of claim_t;
```

Car Object type

```
create type Car_t as object(
regno char(9),
make varchar(12),
model varchar(10),
mdate date,
owner ref customer_t,
value number(8,2)
);
```

Car Table

```
create table Cars of car_t(
regno primary key,
owner references Customers
);
```

Policy object type

```
create type policy_t as object(
pid char(7),      
sdate date,
edate date,
inscar ref car_t,
premium number(6,2),
claims claim_ntab
)
```

Policies Table

```
create table Policies of policy_t(
pid primary key,
inscar references Cars
)nested table claims store as  claims_ntable;
```

Comment: How is `Cars` defined?

Comment: It's best to stick to the standard `varchar2` type for strings, as `char` just wastes space and creates bugs. Also date literals should be written as `date '12017-03-12'`, not `'12 Mar 2017'`. You might get away with it, but it's asking for trouble.

Comment: CAR OBJECT TYPE

create type Car_t as object(
   regno char(9),
   make varchar(12),
   model varchar(10),
   mdate date,
   owner ref customer_t,
   value number(8,2)
);

CAR TABLE

create table Cars of car_t(
regno primary key,
owner references Customers
);

Comment: Please include all necessary code in your question. As mentioned in an answer, the `insert` statement refers to `customer` which I think should be `customers`. Then you get to the real error when you try to insert a `claim_t` into a `claim_ntab` column.

Comment: sorry for your inconvenience,i put all the necessary codes in to a question. i try my query again by changing customer_t to customers_t. but still i get same error

Comment: Strange, I got a different error. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

After correcting the table name (`customer`/`customers`), the next issue is that `customers.claims` is a `claim_ntab` but you are attempting to insert a `claim_t` into it. Try this:

```
insert into policies
select policy_t
       ( 'PLC1234'
       , date '2017-03-12'
       , date '2018-03-12'
       , ref(ca)
       , 175000
       , claim_ntab(claim_t
         ( 'CLAIM1234567'
         , date '2017-02-12'
         , '56000'
         , ref(cu) ) )
         )
from   cars ca
       join customers cu
            on ref(cu) = ca.owner
where  ca.regno = 'CAB3233'
and    cu.cid = '123ABC'
```

Edit: I changed your `where` clause join to ANSI style using an object ref. To be honest I've not used that syntax before and I suspect very few people have, so it will need some testing.

Comment: Hey William,Thanks you very much.

Comment: I've edited my answer to use an object ref join, which runs without error but I don't know if it's right without test data and expected results.

Comment: hey William,I have used your code.it's compile with "0 rows inserted" message.

Answer (score 0):

You named your table `Customers`, note the plural.

So change

```
from cars C,customer T
```

to

```
from cars C,customers T
```

or even better, while you're at it anyway, rewrite it using explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Hey Sticky bit, thank you for your valuable reply.how to do that same operation using REF type instead of joins to link tables?

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO _table1_ (_field1_, _field2_, _field3_)` name of fields, not values
`SELECT _field1_, _field2_, _field3_ FROM _table2_ WHERE ... ;`

`INSERT INTO _table1_ (_field1_, _field2_, _field3_)
VALUES ('some text', 'some text', 'some text');` if you want to add some values